# OpenCV - Save video segments based on certion condition

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

***Aim*** : *Detect the motion and save only the motion periods in files with names of the starting time*.

Now I met the issue about how to save the video to the files with video starting time.

***What I tested*** :

I tested my program part by part. It seems that each part works well except the saving part.

***Running status***: No error. But in the saving folder, there is no video. If I use a static saving path instead, the video will be saved successfully, but the video will be override by the next video. My codes are below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture( 0 )
bgst = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX') 
size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
n = "start_time"

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    dst = bgst.apply(frame)
    dst = np.array(dst, np.int8)

    if np.count_nonzero(dst)>3000:  # use this value to adjust the "Sensitivity“

        print('something is moving %s' %(time.ctime()))

        path = r'E:\OpenCV\Motion_Detection\%s.avi' %n
        out = cv2.VideoWriter( path, fourcc, 50, size )
        out.write(frame)

        key = cv2.waitKey(3)
        if key == 32:
            break

else:
    out.release()
    n = time.ctime()
    print("No motion Detected %s" %n)
```

Comment: In order to avoid the overriding of saved videos, use a `for` loop. Try enclosing the `if` and `else` condition within the `for` loop.

Comment: sorry , will you please make it clear ?I still ....cannot work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture( 0 )
bgst = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX') 
size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
path = r'E:\OpenCV\Motion_Detection\%s.avi' %(time.ctime())
out = cv2.VideoWriter( path, fourcc, 16, size )

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    dst = bgst.apply(frame)
    dst = np.array(dst, np.int8)

    for i in range(number of frames in the video):
        if np.count_nonzero(dst)<3000:  # use this value to adjust the "Sensitivity“

            print("No Motion Detected")
            out.release()

        else:

            print('something is moving %s' %(time.ctime()))
            #label each frame you want to output here 
            out.write(frame(i))

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 32:
        break 

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you see the code there will be a `for` loop, within which the process of saving is done.

I do not know the exact syntax involving for loop with frames, but I hope you have the gist of it. You have to find the number of frames present in the video and set that as the range in the `for` loop.

Each frame gets saved **uniquely** (see the `else` condition.) As I said I do not know the syntax. Please refer and follow this procedure.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for you explanation.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. The thing is that we cannot know how long is the video because it is totally depends on when the motion stops.  I think we needs to find a space that can temporarily store the sequences of images until the motion stops, at last same it to the destination folder. I am not sure if numpy array can do this. I will try this .first.

Comment: glad I could help